# In Pyqt5 how do remove a line caused by the QHBoxLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm just starting to create something in pyqt5 and have found a visual that keeps bothering me. In simple terms I want to know what is causing the white line that is between the blue and orange surface to appear. I would love if you could help me solve this!

The white line

[image]

And here is my code

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def initialize_main(self):

        self.setGeometry(340, 180, 1200, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Text analyzer (in dev)')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('267_Python-512.png'))
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #2e354f; border: none; box-shadow: none;')
        self.initialize_sidebar()

        self.show()


    def initialize_sidebar(self):

        tab = QTabWidget()              # The left tab #22273b
        tab.setStyleSheet("border: none; box-shadow: none; background-color: orange; opacity: 0;")

        container = QHBoxLayout()
        container.addWidget(tab)
        container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        container.addStretch(5)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(container)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
get_screen_size(App)
main_Window = Window()
main_Window.initialize_main()
sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, but I'm not on Windows and cannot test it with its default style. I can suggest you the following, though: 1) Qt stylesheets don't support the `box-shadow` property, remove it; 2) stylesheets are *cascading*, so you should not use generic properties, but prefer [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) instead; 3) try using the [document mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#documentMode-prop) on the tabwidget with `setDocumentMode(True)`; 4) try with `App.setStyle('fusion')` which works better with stylesheets.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you very much, App.setStyle('fusion') is what did the trick! Beautiful.